# Is there a way to open a terminal inside Google Cloud Run?

Tags: terminal, cloud, google-cloud-run

Is there a way to open a terminal inside a running instance of Google Cloud Run? As a git bash or linux terminal...

I have to execute a command when the instance was running.

Answer (score 4):

You can't open a terminal using standard protocols like ssh since Cloud Run only supports exposing a single http port, but you can sort of make your own by providing an endpoint that will run the command and return the result. Just be careful about autoscaling- you might not get the instance you want since there's no way to specify which instance to call.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run exposes only a single endpoint(URL). Due to its nature of autoscaling, all instances it runs up are Stateless, i.e., any command you run are for that particular instance, and also due to autoscaling, the instance might not remain the same.

Adding to what [Ben K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7729578/ben-k) suggested about providing an endpoint for the same, in order to make it stateful, have that Endpoint receive your command directly or have it read from a file stored in a bucket.

Now have this new command appended to a `initialization-script.sh` file stored in GCS which is hit by default whenever your desired Endpoint is hit.
Now all the new instances which are run up due to autoscaling when hitting your desired endpoint, will run this `initialization-script.sh` first.

Hence you have devised a mechanism to store all the previous executed commands on GCS and made it stateful